# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2(x) \cos(b\sin(x)) dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I want to solve the following integral, I have been stuck on.

$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2(x) \cos(b\sin(x)) dx$

where b is real.
I know
$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(b\sin(x)) dx = 2\pi J_0(|b|)$ where $J_0$ is the 0th bessel function, but I have no clue how to tackle the $\cos^2$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My guess is use $\cos^2(x) = 1/2 (1+\cos(2x))$ and then use angle-addition.

Comment: Your title should reflect the actual question not "I need help with [X]". Also I recommend not using asterisks in math equations to denote multiplication. $b\sin(x)$ is understood implicitly to mean $b\cdot \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can drop your modulus signs as $J_0$ is even. [Apply $f\mapsto f^{\prime\prime}+f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) so$$2\pi(J_0^{\prime\prime}+J_0)=\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\sin^2x)\cos(b\sin x)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2x\cos(b\sin x)dx.$$With the right identities, you can rewrite this as e.g. $-\tfrac{2\pi}{b}J_0^\prime(b)=\tfrac{2\pi}{b}J_1(b)$.